# Building Flex Project with RSLs and ANT

Tags: ant, rsls

Can someone give me a code example of how to build a flex project with ANT using framework RSL's?

This is what im currently using but the file SWF generated is way to big;

```
    <target name="main">
        <mxmlc 
            file="${SRC_DIR}/myApp.mxml" 
            output="${DEPLOY_DIR}/myApp.swf"
            actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8"
            keep-generated-actionscript="true"
            incremental="true">
            <!-- Get default compiler options. -->
            <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>

            <!-- List of path elements that form the roots of ActionScript
            class hierarchies. -->
            <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>

            <!-- List of SWC files or directories that contain SWC files. -->
            <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
                <include name="libs" />
                <include name="../bundles/{locale}" />
            </compiler.library-path>
        </mxmlc>
</target>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great description: http://soenkerohde.com/2008/04/using-the-flash-player-cache-for-the-flex-framework/