# Flex ant build - how to reduce swf file size

Tags: flex3

When I build flex project using ant, the resultant .SWF file size is 329 KB. The same project exports .SWF file using flex builder, the size of .SWF file is 108 KB. In flex builder, I am using .SWC library in library path and RSL as framework linkage.

Following is my ant script-

```
<!-- Internal project properties -->

<target name="build-flex" depends="init-flex, build_apphealth">
    <echo>Build Application Health View flex movies completed</echo>
</target>

<target name="init-flex">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="FLEX_HOME" value="${env.FLEX_SDK}"/>
    <taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar"/>
</target>

<target name="build_apphealth">
    <echo>Building Application Health View</echo>
    <mxmlc file="${basedir}/src/appha_guest_installer.mxml" keep-generated-actionscript="false"
           output="${basedir}/bin-release/appha_guest_installer.swf">
            <locale>en_US</locale>
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
        <source-path path-element="${basedir}/src/locale/{locale}"></source-path>
        <compiler.library-path file="${basedir}/../wizard_framework/bin/wizard_framework.swc" append="true"/>
        <include-resource-bundles>ErrorMessages</include-resource-bundles>
        <include-resource-bundles>Strings</include-resource-bundles>
    </mxmlc>
</target>
```

I feel that there should some additional attribute required in compiler.library-path option. Kindly let me know what could be the possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use runtime-shared-library-path in your ant build file? Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730715/building-flex-project-with-rsls-and-ant) link for more details.

Comment: Thanks brother for your suggestion. It worked. I just added an attribute in static-rsls="false" in <mxmlc> tag and found that ant generates swf with reduced size.